# Selenium automation got an error when trying to automate website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, request

Can someone tell me about selenium automation? I was working with the selenium older version but recently I updated my selenium version 4.x. And now I am unable to automate any website. Provide me a small script which simply go to google.com.

I tried selenium version 4.x and I'm unable to get desire results.

Comment: No error? probably you have to adapt functions obsoletes like "find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)" to find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath). And driver version compability

Comment: Share your code trials and error trace from console. **"Provide me a small script which simply go to google.com"** - This is not a good way of asking question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _I'm unable to get desire results_: What error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install webdriver_manager using "pip install webdriver_manager"

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://google.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use Selenium

Basic code

```html
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

browser = Chrome()
url = 'https://google.com'
browser.get(url)
browser.quit()
```

But after use this code please install WebDriver
This is Tutirial how install driver
[Tuturial Link](https://selenium-python.com/install-chromedriver-chrome)

[Driver Link here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: This is not a good answer, but question isnt good also, didnt explain error